# Javascript simple Form Validation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I have been trying to figure this simple code out. I have it down to where the IF Firstname is empty or == 1, it will ALERT, but the final IF statement is always ringing true and doesn't alert false or true. Any ideas?

```
﻿function validateForm()
{
    var firstname=document.getElementById('firstname').value.trim();


var count=0;
if (firstname.length==0)
 { alert("EMPTY");
  document.getElementById("err_firstname").innerHTML="<br><span class='errorbar'>*This is a required field</span>";
  } else  {
   count++; 
   alert("COUNTED");
   document.getElementById("err_firstname").innerHTML="";
  }

  if (count==1)
      {
   return true; 
  alert("true");
   } else {
   document.getElementById("err_allerrors").innerHTML="<br><span class='errorbar'>*There is required information missing. Please enter all required data.</span>";
      return false;
             alert("false");       

     }
    //Verified         
}
```

Answer (score 1):

return before `alert()` is the problem

Comment: Imagine this code without all Alerts. It still returns true.

Comment: The first statement returns EMPTY or COUNTED. I removed the two alerts in the second statement and still returns TRUE.

Comment: When you call your function, the count variable may be is increased only once time(no more). So that's why it almost return 1